# How to detect "potential loss of precision in explicit type conversion" in C++ code by using static analysis tool or compiler flag

Tags: c++, type-conversion, static-analysis

For example:

```
    long long a = ....;
    int b;
    b = (int) a;
```

Is there a gcc flag or static analysis tools like Sonarqube can detect this case?

Comment: Do you want to catch just C-style casts or all narrowing conversions? Because explicit cast is basically "trust me, I know what I'm doing" for the compiler.

Comment: C-style casts like that should always be a red flags that you're doing something wrong. I would rather see a rule to flag all such casts.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can use -Wold-style-cast for C-style casts. But I need to find narrowing conversions that may lead to loss of precision

Comment: `-Wfloat-conversion` or `-Wconversion` should do it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think those flags are for implicit type conversion(not for explicit conversion)

Comment: They are, so as @Someprogrammerdude says, the explicit casts are kind of you promising the compiler things will work. You can check the range against `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` before the cast, but that is something you have to implement and not something that will generate a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for explicit type castings is a strange task. The developer obviously meant that he wanted to "cut off" high bits using explicit type casting. Nevertheless, I would venture to say that the task was actually different: one had to port a 32-bit application to the 64-bit platform. In this case, yes, it is a very relevant task to detect dangerous explicit types castings. If it is so, there is a solution. There is a special set of diagnostics related to porting in the PVS-Studio analyzer. Examples:

- [V202](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v202/). Explicit conversion from memsize type to 32-bit integer type.
- [V220](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v220/). Suspicious sequence of types castings: memsize -> 32-bit
  integer -> memsize.
- [V221](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v221/). Suspicious sequence of types castings:
  pointer -> memsize -> 32-bit integer.
- and [others](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/#64CPP).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) which uses Clang as a C/C++ parser, and Clang detects such issues.